# How do I call an Objective-C method from Javascript with a single parameter and handle it in Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webview, native

I am new to this kind of application. Can any one help with my requirement really helpful.
I have iPad application in which javascript calls native function with a parameter . I am getting the same in `webview` `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`...delegate method. I am able to call native functions which are send from javascript but when function comes with a parameter how can fetch what is the function and what is the parameter.
Please guide me.

posting the code here below.

```
window.location.href = "js2ios://getNotiData(" +groupId  + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, call from your JS should be:

```
window.location.href = "js2ios://getNotiData?groupId=XXX
```

Then, in your `UIViewController` which contains the `UIWebView`, you'll need to add a delegation for the web view (called: `UIWebViewDelegate`). The following method is the important one for you:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
      NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
      if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"js2ios:"]) {
           NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:request.url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
           NSArray *queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems;
           NSString *param1 = [self valueForKey:@"groupId" fromQueryItems:queryItems];

           // NOW CALL YOUR OBJECTIVE-C METHOD WITH param1 !

           return NO;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer. I tried with the below approach and I am sure yours is the best code. I am posting my code as well.NSArray *urlArray = [urlStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
            NSString *paramsString;
                if([urlArray count] > 1){
                    paramsString = [urlArray objectAtIndex:1];
                }
                NSString *strGroupid=@"groupId=";
                paramsString=[paramsString substringFromIndex:[strGroupid length]];